# How to ignore some features in updatemode in an InstallScript project?

Tags: installshield, updates, installscript, installshield-2012

I am developing an InstallShield InstallScript project (not MSI) and currently working on the *"updatemode"* behaviour of the `setup.exe` program.

I would like to know if it is possible to ignore the update of one specific feature and still update the other ones.

The problem is that the program needs to determine whether the feature should be updated during the execution, which means the feature has to be embedded in the update program.

I've already tried to use the InstallScript function `FeatureSetItem`, but when I set my feature to false, the feature is not ignored, but uninstalled by my update program.

Any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what it is that you don't want to be updated or why, but if it's just files then set the components for the feature to "overwrite by date" or "overwrite by version".

Comment: I had already thought about that, but the problem is that there are many script files in the component, for which the date is not a reliable criterion...

Comment: @gruntzy: Please explain why date would not be a reliable criterion in your case.

Comment: Well, assume that our component contains a "FileA.txt", installed by Installshield on a date Date1. Then, on Date2, another setup.exe is generated, but for some reasons (and that happens), that setup is not installed at the moment. Now, on Date3, "FileA" is modified on the target machine, before we use the new setup.exe... I guess that installshield will not replace that file, even if we should...

Answer (score 0):

In InstallShield, go to "Releases". Create a new "Release" and then go through the Release Wizard.
One of the windows in the release wizard allows you to check/uncheck the features for that release. Simply uncheck the features that you do not want to update. This way, those features will not be included when you build that particular release configuration. They will still be included if you build using the original release configuration.